# SASS foreach on li with certain classes

Tags: css, foreach, sass

I've been searching all over for an answer to this question for a specific issue I am looking at with SASS. I am wanting to start with an li at 100% opacity but then have it loop through the li's with certain classes and subtract 5% opacity using the transparentize function. The issue though is the foreach loop, as I don't know how many li's with a certain class I'll have. Let me see if I can explain it with code, basically I'll show you the long form and if someone can help me convert it into a short foreach that would be great.

```
li {
    ... styles are here ...

    &.Language {
        background-color: $red
    }

    &.Language.comp-1 {
        background-color: transparentize($red, 0.10);
     }

     &.Language.comp-2 {
        background-color: transparentize($red, 0.20);
     }

     &.Language.comp-3 {
        background-color: transparentize($red, 0.30);
    }

     &.Language.comp-4 {
        background-color: transparentize($red, 0.40);
    }

    &.Language.comp-5 {
        background-color: transparentize($red, 0.50);
    }
}
```

If I was going to do this in PHP this is how I would do it, I just need the SASS version:

```
$transparency_increment = .10
foreach( $item as $li ) {
   background-color: transparentize( $red, $transparency_increment);
   $transparency_increment + .10;
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense, I'm sure I'll have to use the `nth` item somewhere since the exact count will be unknown. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Isn't the upper limit known though (10)? Anything more than 10 would have a transparency >= 1, which would all be equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, I was using an example - I am thinking of setting it to 5% or less. I just don't want to have the classes hard coded so if I move them around one doesn't end up being out of place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`@for` control directive](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#id11)

This should do what you want:

```
$red: #ff0000;

@mixin foo($prefix, $num, $step){
    @for $i from 1 through $num {
        #{$prefix}-#{$i} {
            background-color: transparentize($red, $i * $step);
        }
    }
}

li {
    @include foo('&.Language.comp', 10, 0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested and extracted from [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_mixins.scss)

```
@mixin transparent_steps_bg($bg_color, $amount, $tranparancy_amount) {
  @while $amount> 0 {
  .comp-#{$amount} { background-color: transparentize($bg_color, $amount * tranparancy_amount); }
  $amount: $amount - 1;
}
```